# Numpy - Fill image with corrsp. I given array of [u,v, I]

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array that has a N*3 matrix of `[u, v, I]`. Pixel positions and `I` intensity for that pixel.

I need to generate fill an image of the corresponding `I` from the set of pixels in that numpy array. Right now I have a for loop to do it but it is quite slow. What is a faster way to do this?

```
dmap_raw = np.zeros((raw_img_size[1], raw_img_size[0])).astype(np.float32)
for i in range(0, velodata_cam_proj.shape[0]):
    u = velodata_cam_proj[i,0]
    v = velodata_cam_proj[i,1]
    Z = velodata_cam_proj[i,2]
    dmap_raw[int(v),int(u)] = Z*100
```

Comment: Please show your working solution with the for-loop. It will help to understand your question.

Comment: Okay I have added the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dmap_raw = np.zeros((raw_img_size[1], raw_img_size[0])).astype(np.float32)

u = velodata_cam_proj[:,0].astype('int')
v = velodata_cam_proj[:,1].astype('int')
Z = velodata_cam_proj[:,2]
dmap_raw[v, u] = Z*100
```